# Dragging board less windows in WPF- How to Do it efficiently?

Tags: wpf, drag

That's the code i have to drag my window. It kinda works! Kind of...

```
Private Point startPoint;

private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
}
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Point relative = e.GetPosition(null);
        Point AbsolutePos = new Point(relative.X + this.Left, relative.Y + this.Top);
        this.Top = AbsolutePos.Y - startPoint.Y;
        this.Left = AbsolutePos.X - startPoint.X;
    }
}
```

The problem is if i move the mouse too fast, it will go out of the window and stop raising the movemouse event. Second, the dragging window is not smooth at all which makes me believed i'm not doing it the right way. Third, I've tried this on Window_MouseLeftButtonDown which would fire the event just once per mouse click.
I'm a beginner, a simple example free of Dropping and Data transferring would be appreciated by me and many others beginners like me. thanks in advance to Stack OverFlow users willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Losing the mouse is a result of failing to capture the mouse.  The standard procedure is:

- [capture the mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx) in the mouse down event and record the mouse position
- handle the mouse motion in the mouse move event if the button is depressed
- [release the mouse capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture.aspx) in the mouse up event and perform any final processing

As far as the performance, you are going about it the right way.  The speed is limited by the repainting of the window itself and any windows the window passes over and how fast your computer is and what else is going on on computer while you are dragging it.

Comment: Seems like wpf is quite a heavy technology , to drag notepad around, it goes smooth but this wpf window flicks a little. I've tried Eugen's answer, that single line makes a miracle replacing all the code i had after hours to get to the result i got. the window still flicks just like on my code, but i don't loose the pointer no more.

Comment: Thanks for your guide lines i'll try again another time to see if i can create a efficient code on my own. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is actually simpler than you think. Place this line

```
MouseDown += delegate { DragMove(); };
```

in your constructor and you are good to go :)

Comment: Thanks Eugen, coudn't find this beautiful line no googlewhere, works just fine, but the window still flicks, it must be my computer performance when the deal is WPF.

Comment: it should be your graphics card, it moves very smooth at me. I have a nVidia GTX 570.